# Añadir métodos incrementar y decrementar en C

Tags: c

tengo que, utilizando la base de código, implementar dos funciones (incrementar y decrementar) fuera del main.

El código es este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv){

  if (argc != 3){
   printf(" Error.\n son necesarios 3 argumentos: %s operacion valor ", argv[0]);
   exit(1);
  }
  if (strcmp("increment", argv[1]) == 0)
     printf(" resultado  de la operacion --> resultado = %d\n", (atoi(argv[2]))+ 1);
  else
    if (strcmp("decrement", argv[1]) == 0)
       printf(" resultado  de la operacion --> resultado = %d\n", (atoi(argv[2]))- 1);
   else
     printf("Operacion no permitida\n");
}
```

He intentado hacer lo siguiente pero sigue sin funcionar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int incrementar(int a) {
    printf(" resultado al incrementar es --> " + (a + 1));
}

int decrementar(int a) {
    printf(" resultado al decrementar es --> " + (a - 1));
}

int main (int argc, char **argv){
    incrementar((atoi(argv[2])));
    if (argc != 3){
        printf(" Error.\n son necesarios 3 argumentos: %s operacion valor ", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }
    if (strcmp("increment", argv[1]) == 0)
    printf(" resultado  de la operacion --> resultado = %d\n", (atoi(argv[2]))+ 1);
    else
        if (strcmp("decrement", argv[1]) == 0)
        printf(" resultado  de la operacion --> resultado = %d\n", (atoi(argv[2]))- 1);
        else
            printf("Operacion no permitida\n");
}
```

Ayuda, he probado a hacer los métodos con parámetros argc y argv pero tampoco me funciona.

Comment: ¿ El compilador te ha generado algún aviso (*warning*) con ese código ? ¿ Podrías incorporar esos posibles mensajes a la pregunta ? Para completarla y que otros usuarios con el mismo problema puedan encontrarla. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. En las funciones `incrementar` y `decrementar`, declaras un retorno tipo `int` pero no retornas nada.
   Mi sugerencia es que en esas funciones no imprimas nada y retornes un valor, por ejemplo:

   ```
   int incrementar(int a) {
       return ++a;
   }
   ```

   Con esto, la función tiene sentido con su nombre, pues devolverá el valor de `a` incrementado en una unidad. Si insistes en imprimir dentro de la función, mi sugerencia sería cambiar el nombre de la función por algo como `imprimirIncremento()`.
2. Siguiendo mi primera sugerencia, una vez tienes implementadas ambas funciones, debes llamarlas desde tu código. Volviendo al ejemplo de incrementar, podría llamarse directamente al momento de imprimir el resultado, por ejemplo:

   ```
   printf(" resultado  de la operacion --> resultado = %d\n", (incrementar(atoi(argv[2]))));
   ```

Poniendo todo en conjunto, tu programa podría quedar así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int incrementar(int a) {
    return ++a;
}

int decrementar(int a) {
    return --a;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv){
    if (argc != 3){
        printf(" Error.\n son necesarios 3 argumentos: %s operacion valor ", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (strcmp("increment", argv[1]) == 0)
        printf(" resultado  de la operacion --> resultado = %d\n", (incrementar(atoi(argv[2]))));
    else if (strcmp("decrement", argv[1]) == 0)
        printf(" resultado  de la operacion --> resultado = %d\n", (decrementar(atoi(argv[2]))));
    else
        printf("Operacion no permitida\n");
}
```